# Immutable objects builder

Tags: java, builder

Would it be considered a good practice to store the builder instance inside the instance that it has built? The thing is that I quite often find myself in a situation when I need to create a very similiar object to the one that I already have. Presumable this object has many 8-10 fields. Normally, with a mutable object I would have just used setter.

For instance, lets take the classic Bloch's `NutricionFacts` example:

```
public class NutritionFacts {
    private final int servingSize;
    private final int servings;
    private final int calories;
    private final int fat;
    private final int sodium;
    private final int carbohydrate;

    private final Builder builder;

    public static class Builder {
        // Required parameters
        private final int servingSize;
        private final int servings;
        // Optional parameters - initialized to default values
        private int calories = 0;
        private int fat = 0;
        private int carbohydrate = 0;
        private int sodium = 0;

        public Builder(int servingSize, int servings) {
            this.servingSize = servingSize;
            this.servings = servings;
        }
        public Builder calories(int val)
        { calories = val; return this; }
        public Builder fat(int val)
        { fat = val; return this; }
        public Builder carbohydrate(int val)
        { carbohydrate = val; return this; }
        public Builder sodium(int val)
        { sodium = val; return this; }

        public NutritionFacts build() {
            return new NutritionFacts(this);
        }
    }

    private NutritionFacts(Builder builder) {
        servingSize = builder.servingSize;
        servings = builder.servings;
        calories = builder.calories;
        fat = builder.fat;
        sodium = builder.sodium;
        carbohydrate = builder.carbohydrate;
        this.builder = builder;
    }
}
```

I have modified it a bit so I can access the builder instance if I want to make a simmiliar copy in the future?

What do you think?

Comment: Or you might have a clone method.

Comment: @dystroy  Clone is not a good option since the class in immutable and the clone would be exactly the same as the first instance without the ability to modify.

Comment: ante's answer is probably the right path and that said, NO you should not have a reference to the builder in the built class. The point of an immutable object is that it is IMMUTABLE. Having a reference to a reachable mutable object makes you supposeded immutable object mutable. What if two threads start using the same builder to do different things? You previously thread-safe immutable object is now not thread-safe.

Comment: ante answer is just fine. I am really baffled by the fact that I haven't stumbled upon such a use case or that the standard builder pattern does not provide a constructor taking the template object as argument. I use it extensively. All the time I am in a need of creating a simmilar object to the one that I already have. Is it not a common practice to fetch some object from the DBMS, then set some flag and persist it back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens if you reuse the `Builder` to build a second instance? The `Builder` in the first instance would then produce instances similar to the second instance. Probably not what you expected.

I would suggest an option to create the `Builder` with a template instance.

```
    public Builder(NutritionFacts template) {
        this.servingSize = template.getServingSize();
        ...
    }
```